# Spring Security - Custom LDAP Authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I came across a difficult scenario with my Spring MVC web application.

My application is using LDAP authentication. When I hosted this application in outside could environment, the authentication failed as there is no public LDAP url for my organization. They don't have public LDAP url due to security reasons.

Is it possible, that I create a authentication service inside my organization network and and my application hit that service every time a user tries to authenticate??

How can I separate authentication from my application?

Answer (score 0):

For this You have to deploy 2 applications. First one is a service application in your organization network. This service will be called from your outside application for authentication purposes.

Comment: I agree. This is the solution I have in my mind. But, what should my auth service should return to my actual application on cloud. What data should be exchanged in communication?